# repeated selection of same option of Shiny radioButtons

Tags: r, shiny, radio-button, reactive

I made a Shiny app with two panels. In the first panel, radio buttons are shown. When one of the buttons is selected, the app moves to the second panel, and in this panel the value of the selected radio button is shown. In this second panel there is an action button 'Back to first panel'.

When clicking on this button, the program moves back to the first panel. Now when the user clicks on the same radio button as before, the program does not move to the second panel as it did the first time.

Given the Shiny mechanism, I can understand this, after all the value of the input (i.e. the radio button input) did not change.

Nevertheless, I would like to change the program so that it always moves to the second panel when clicking on any radio button, even if it is the same radio button as having clicked on before.

Is there a way to make the program behave that way?

The R code is as follows:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- tagList(
  navbarPage(
    title=NULL, id = "navBar",
    tabPanel(title = "Panel1", uiOutput('showRadioButtons')),
    tabPanel(title = "Panel2", uiOutput('showChoice'), hr(), actionButton("goBack", "Back to first panel"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session)
{
  observe({
    shinyjs::hide(selector = '#navBar li a[data-value="Panel2"]')
  })

  output$showRadioButtons <- renderUI({
    radioButtons(inputId = "entries", label = NULL, choiceNames  = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), choiceValues = c(1,2,3,4), selected = 0)
  })

  output$showChoice <- renderUI({
    if (length(input$entries)>0)
      return(input$entries) else return(NULL)

  })

  observe({
    if (length(input$entries)>0)
    {
      shinyjs::hide(selector = '#navBar li a[data-value="Panel1"]')
      shinyjs::show(selector = '#navBar li a[data-value="Panel2"]')
      updateNavbarPage(session, "navBar", selected="Panel2")
    }
  })

  observe({
    if (input$goBack>0)
    {
      shinyjs::hide(selector = '#navBar li a[data-value="Panel2"]')
      shinyjs::show(selector = '#navBar li a[data-value="Panel1"]')
      updateNavbarPage(session, "navBar", selected="Panel1")
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Can you use `updateRadioButtons` and update the `selected=NULL` during the `input$goBack`? That way any input will be new.

Comment: I tried this but did not get it work. When returning from the second panel to the first one, all of the options are (indeed) deselected, nevertheless when then choosing the same option as before, the program does not move to the second panel again.

Comment: Have you tried the answer below?

Comment: Yes, I did! It only works when changing 'selected=0' in 'selected=4' in the updateRadioButtons call, and adding the condition '(input$entries!=4)' as condition in output$showChoice and in the first observe. In  that way the fourth option is used as a kind of dummy option, but I hope for a nicer solution.

Comment: It is my impression that the trick you mentioned only works when 'selected' gets assigned a 'real' existing option. 1, 2, 3 or 4 are existing options, 0 is not. But I would like to avoid adding a dummy option if possible.

Comment: I have copied the full code into my answer and it is working just fine but maybe I am not understanding the problem. The dummy variable 0 you are taking about is one that you also used when initializing the radio button, `radioButtons(inputId = "entries",....selected=0)`. I am basically re-rendering the radio buttons the same way you initially rendered them.

Comment: Yes, still same problem. The first time I click on option 'C' the program switches to the second panel.Then I click on 'Back to first' panel. Then I click again on option 'C', but now the program does not switch to the second panel any more, however it should (i.e. that is what I want).

Comment: Hmm, the only thing I can think of is that we are using different versions of shiny. I am using v1.1.0

Comment: Also, I am using shinyjs 1.0

Comment: I had version 1.0.5 of the shiny package and upgraded it to version 1.2.0 and now it works! Many thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this by pushing an update to the radio buttons using `updateRadioButtons` when the back button is pushed.

```
 observe({
    if (input$goBack>0)
    {
      updateRadioButtons(session,inputId = "entries", label=NULL, 
       choiceNames  = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), choiceValues = c(1,2,3,4), selected = 0)
      shinyjs::hide(selector = '#navBar li a[data-value="Panel2"]')
      shinyjs::show(selector = '#navBar li a[data-value="Panel1"]')
      updateNavbarPage(session, "navBar", selected="Panel1")
    }
  })
```

Full code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- tagList(
  navbarPage(
    title=NULL, id = "navBar",
    tabPanel(title = "Panel1", uiOutput('showRadioButtons')),
    tabPanel(title = "Panel2", uiOutput('showChoice'), hr(), actionButton("goBack", "Back to first panel"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session)
{
  observe({
    shinyjs::hide(selector = '#navBar li a[data-value="Panel2"]')
  })

  output$showRadioButtons <- renderUI({
    radioButtons(inputId = "entries", label = NULL, choiceNames  = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), choiceValues = c(1,2,3,4), selected = 0)
  })

  output$showChoice <- renderUI({
    if (length(input$entries)>0)
      return(input$entries) else return(NULL)

  })

  observe({
    if (length(input$entries)>0)
    {
      shinyjs::hide(selector = '#navBar li a[data-value="Panel1"]')
      shinyjs::show(selector = '#navBar li a[data-value="Panel2"]')
      updateNavbarPage(session, "navBar", selected="Panel2")
    }
  })

  observe({
    if (input$goBack>0)
    {
      updateRadioButtons(session,inputId = "entries", label=NULL, 
                         choiceNames  = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), choiceValues = c(1,2,3,4), selected = 0)
      shinyjs::hide(selector = '#navBar li a[data-value="Panel2"]')
      shinyjs::show(selector = '#navBar li a[data-value="Panel1"]')
      updateNavbarPage(session, "navBar", selected="Panel1")
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```